# Connecting to Podmans socket 2375 under Windows

Tags: windows, podman

The internet is full with helpful tips on how to set up either *Docker* to expose the management port 2375 and connect to it, or how to configure it to run under Windows (or Podman under Linux).

But I couldn't find a guide on how to set up **Podman**s socket 2375 to be exposed under **Windows** (and behave mostly like Docker). Especially since I don't have root rights, so I can't do stuff like "Enter the WSL and run `sudo ...`". But Podman is sold to be a drop-in replacement for this simple case, without the need for root rights, so there should be a way.

Please, does someone know how to set up *Podman* under *Windows* for this?

Edit: This is only for integration tests, so I don't care about security. And we need the socket only exposed to our local PC, no other PCs.

Comment: Generally, enabling unauthenticated access to the Docker socket over the network is a _major_ security issue; it's all but trivial to use that to compromise the entire host.  Why do you think you want to enable it?

Comment: @DavidMaze Edited, this is only for integration tests. Tests are the only purpose we use Docker at all.